# É necessário memorizar tudo sobre arquivos XML, enquanto tenho o IDE pra fazer isso por mim?

Tags: android, android-layout

Tô começando a aprender Android e queria saber se é necessário memorizar os atributos que um componente tem como `layout_height`, `layout_width`, `layout_gravity`, etc.

Tem certos atributos que é difícil de lembrar, então acabo apelando pro IDE: arrasta e cola. Eu queria saber se isso tá inibindo meu aprendizado ou é normal. Eu arrasto e colo mas tenho noção do que é cada coisa. Se eu criar um app assim pode se dizer que "Eu" criei? Porque o importante mesmo é a estrutura de dados, meu algoritmo, não é?

Comment: Eu acredito que o pessoal está negativando sua pergunta por que parece ser baseada em opiniões  , não vou arriscar responder por que não conheço o ambiente de desenvolvimento android , mas acredito que em qualquer ambiente de desenvolvimento e essencial  'saber o que você esta usando em seu código'

Comment: Confesso que fiquei meio receoso em fazer este tipo de pergunta pelo fato de se tretar de uma opinião,  já vi várias perguntas relacionadas a opinião .-.. Mas tudo bem, tô indo perguntar lá no Yahoo Respostas. Valeu e desculpa qualquer incômodo.

Comment: @D3ll4ry Já conhece o nosso [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)? Lá você pode fazer esse tipo de pergunta sem problema.

Comment: Sinceramente, acho que é uma pergunta interessante, pois é uma dúvida que algum novato ou até mesmo alguns desenvolvedores podem vir a ter. Não acho que deveria ser considerada uma pergunta ruin.'

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sou programador profissional - estou na graduação ainda. Tenho uns 1~1.5 anos de programação em Android.

Sempre gosto de fazer meus *layout* usando o *Edit Code*, pois me sinto mais confortável nele. Porém, isso não quer dizer que não uso a área Design. Ninguém é obrigado a saber todos os componentes e *tags* XML que está usando. O XML é uma linguagem de marcação assim como HTML e XHTML. No XML, posso criar minha *tag* personalizada e talvez a IDE não reconheça aquele "objeto XML personalizado", e você será obrigado a usar o *Edit Code*.

Sempre uso a área de arrastar e soltar, quando esqueço o nome de algum componente ou atributo e fico configurando ali mesmo (apesar de sempre ficar perdido).

Recomendo a você que se acostume a usar os dois. Já tive situações que o IDE não reconhecia a tag XML, como é caso de um `Fragment` de mapas e, se não me engano, o LoginButton do Facebook - não aparecia quais atributos poderiam ser modificados, porém o assistente visual desenhava corretamente.

Independente de qual modo esta desenvolvendo acho bom não desistir no meio do caminho por uma indecisão de IDE. Mesmo não gostando, aprenda a usar as duas formas.